# Match selector to current set and children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find a way to apply a selector to a JQuery object such that it matches the set that is contained within this object and also does a "find" through all their children.

The problem I have is that I could only find the methods "filter" which does not descend the tree and "find" which only starts its search at the children of the current elements.

I created an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ppd51pef/

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <span>first:</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foo bar">
    <span>second:</span>
</div>
```

And the Javascript that goes with it:

```
var foos = $(".foo");
foos.find(".bar").append("<span>find</span> ");
foos.filter(".bar").append("<span>filter</span> ");
foos.find(".bar").addBack().filter(".bar").append("<span>ugly</span> ");
```

Here I have a jquery object "foos" that matches the two "foo" classes. Given "foos" I want to select the two "bar" classes.

The output of the example is:

```
first: find ugly 
second: filter ugly
```

Basically I'm looking for a less ugly way of achieving what the third of the three queries does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) version with a selector

```js
var foos = $(".foo");
foos.find(".bar").addBack('.bar').append("<span>ugly</span> ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <span>first:</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo bar">
  <span>second:</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a little better performance wise I guess, but still ugly code because I have to state the selector ".bar" twice.